# Electron Forge template with mobx-react observers

Tags: mobx-react, electron-forge

I have recently started playing around with [Electron Forge](https://beta.electronforge.io/cli/package) and I think it is an awesome tool. I have also been doing some work with the [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) package and have been using the observer feature.

Creating an electron-forge project based on the react template, I modify the app.jsx file to look like

```
import React from 'react';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <h2>Welcome to React!</h2>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

When I run the application it errors out with

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: /home/me/project/src/app.jsx: Unexpected token (4:0)
```

Where line 4 is

```
@observer export default class App extends React.Component {
```

From what I have played with in the past I used something like webpack to compile everything so it runs properly. Based on the [description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-forge) of the project I shouldn't need to worry about webpack.

How do I use Electron Forge with react, mobx, and the observers feature?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` package.
2. Add `transform-decorators-legacy` and `transform-class-properties` to babel plugins.

Example contents of `.compilerc` file:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "1.6.0" } }],
          "react"
        ],
        "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties", "transform-async-to-generator", "transform-es2015-classes", "react-hot-loader/babel"],
        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "1.6.0" } }],
          "react"
        ],
        "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties", "transform-async-to-generator", "transform-es2015-classes"],
        "sourceMaps": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```